# Create a time table (hours by hours) in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I generate the following table in BigQuery:

```
    +---------------------+
    | mydate              |
    +---------------------+
    | 2010-01-01 00:00:00 |
    | 2010-01-01 01:00:00 |
    | 2010-01-01 02:00:00 |
    | 2010-01-01 03:00:00 |
    | 2010-01-01 04:00:00 |
    | 2010-01-01 05:00:00 |
    +---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select ts
from unnest(generate_timestamp_array('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2010-01-01 05:00:00', interval 1 hour)) ts
```

with output

[image]

Another option (based on @Daniel's comment and @Khilesh's answer)

```
select timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00') + make_interval(hour => hours_to_add)
from unnest(generate_array(0,5)) AS hours_to_add
```

obviously with same output as above

Comment: Just to add to this, there are a couple other array generation methods that can be found in the BigQuery documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_array

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2010-01-01 00:00:00", INTERVAL hours_to_add HOURS) as mydate 
from
(SELECT num1 as hours_to_add FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,2400)) AS num1)
```

Output :

```
+---------------------+
| mydate              |
+---------------------+
| 2010-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 01:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 02:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 03:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 04:00:00 |
| 2010-01-01 05:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```